# How to get the data with the same column in two txt file to an new txt?

Tags: python, dataset

I need to get over 200,000 annotations from the original annotation txt file(B.txt) by comparing the first column string.

For example:

A.txt is like

00001.jpg

00002.jpg

00004.jpg

...

B.txt is like

00001.jpg 12 3 1 33

00002.jpg 32 4 2 2

00003.jpg 23 4 5 1

00004.jpg 3 5 3 1

00005.jpg 2 4 1 1

...

I want get a C.txt like

00001.jpg 12 3 1 33

00002.jpg 32 4 2 2

00004.jpg 3 5 3 1

...

The code I worte seems like can't get any line wrote in C.txt

```
alines = open('A.txt', 'r').readlines() 
blines = open('B.txt', 'r').readlines()
fw = open('C.txt', 'w')
for al in alines:
    for bl in blines:
        if str(al) in str(bl):
            fw.write(bl)
fw.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `alines` and `blines` lists contain the lines ending with the '\n' symbols so the comparison always fails.

The following code strips the '\n' symbols and also eliminates the second "for" cycle:

```py
with open('A.txt', 'r') as fh:
    # Splitlines gets rid of the '\n' endlines
    alines = fh.read().splitlines()
with open('B.txt', 'r') as fh:
    # Splitlines gets rid of the '\n' endlines
    blines = fh.read().splitlines()
with open('C.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for line in blines:
        # Split the file name
        parts = line.split(' ', 1)
        # Look up the filename
        if parts[0] in alines:
            fh.write(line + '\n')
```